# Why Cloud Vision API returns not exact matches?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use the Cloud Vision API to identify similar images in a webpage using example from https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web#web_detection_requests. I enabled the WEB_DETECTION feature and provided the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leFWX.png) as input.

The API returned the collection of *PagesWithMatchingImages*, that are very similar to the input image, but are not exact matches. Both records with *FullMatchingImages* and *PartialMatchingImages* are affected by the problem. Is this expected behavior for the WEB_DETECTION feature? Is there an option to control or show how similar the found images are to the input image?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the result score still exists... no documentation confirmation.
[https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#WebImage[enter](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#WebImage%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwLVI.jpg)

But sth like FullMatching should exist:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).